# How to route Flask url based on user form input in HTML?

Tags: python, flask, url-routing

I have an html form where a user can enter a stock ticker. After submitting the ticker I'd like the app to redirect to a url that has the entered ticker in the url path and returns the ticker name.

**Code:**

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def stockInfo():
    if request.method == "POST":
        ticker = request.form['ticker'].upper()
        return redirect('/<ticker>')
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/<ticker>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def success(ticker):
    return '<h1>The ticker' + ticker + 'was entered </h1>'
```

What I would like to happen is when the user submits the ticker `"NFLX"` it routes to `/NFLX` and returns `"The ticker NFLX was entered"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using Flask's [url_for](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#url-building) function:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def stockInfo():
    if request.method == "POST":
        ticker = request.form['ticker'].upper()
        return redirect(url_for('success', ticker=ticker))
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/<ticker>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def success(ticker):
    return '<h1>The ticker' + ticker + 'was entered </h1>'
```

Comment: added url_for to imports and worked perfectly thanks